# Problems with one data type going from Access to Excel

Tags: database, excel, ms-access-2003

I have been trying to create a database query based off an Excel sheet and have a column of part numbers I want to sort by user defined input. Access returns a numeric overflow after I type in the part number I want to sort by.

Part numbers are a text format in Excel (however, some of them are only numeric). I have tried reformatting all of them into text on Excel already and I still get the same error.

If anybody can help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have had trouble with long numbers in Excel too.  If you put an apostrophe (') in front of them, Excel generally understands them to be a literal text.  That was such a hassle that I ended up just prepending a letter to long, numeric identifiers then discarding that identifier when taking stuff out of Excel.  Not sure if there's a better solution.

Comment: If you have a single column of part numbers, I'm not sure what it means to "type in the Part number I want to sort by."

Comment: If I run the query, I have it set up to prompt me for the Part number, I type it in and then it returns all records associated with the part number.